# Use selenium IDE to change Firefox Preferences for SDK Addon testing

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-sdk, xul, selenium-ide

I am using Selenium IDE to test some behavior in my FireFox SDK Add-On. For example, I load a page and determine that the content script is executing at intended. In my plugin, I use simple-prefs to set some user defined preferences.

For example, I would like to load a page and then ensure that if a preference is changed, that the content script received the update and made the necessary changes to the page based on the new setting.

when I try to navigate with Selenium-IDE to the plugin configuration page `chrome://mozapps/content/extensions/extensions.xul?type=extensions` / `about:addons`. I am able to use Selenium to select an entry (`<richlistitem />`), but I cannot click any of the buttons within the entry because they are not part of the XUL dom. I have tried using Selenium to send enter, tab, clicks, double clicks to the appropriate `<richlistitem />` but there is no way of interacting with the "inner part" of the item.

I have also tried going down the path of using selenium to modify entries via `about:config`, however, the area with all of the entires is just an XUL `<treechildren />` and you have no way of targeting individual entries.

Is there a convenient way to change addon setting as part of an automated workflow with selenium-ide?

Comment: Found this for selenium web driver: http://rostislav-matl.blogspot.com/2011/09/setting-firefox-preferences-via.html

Answer (score -1):

It seems you should use Selenium Web driver , by driver you can set preference